# firebase-core:12.0.1 not found

Tags: android, firebase, build.gradle

I have created a firebase project and it says I have to modify the core version to 12 according to the picture

[image]

The default code is 9.6.1. So, I changed that number to 12.0.1

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
```

However, the sync failed with the following error

```
Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Update the gms plugin:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0' // google-services plugin
```

and the firebase lib:

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
```

Also add google maven to your build.gradle file:

```
allprojects {
    // ...
    repositories {
        // ...
        maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
       }
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should I also change `firebase-messaging` to 16?

Comment: messaging is in version 17 already, https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: So, should I change both of them to 17?

Comment: each individual library has its own version, you should use 16 for core and 17 for messaging.

Comment: I get `Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0` and `Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0`

Comment: Did you update the gms pluging and used "implementation" instead of "compile"?

Comment: Not very professional. Can you update the answer to show how?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171705/discussion-between-levi-albuquerque-and-mahmood).

Comment: @mahmood try my answer it helps you?

Comment: sure, to update the plugin you need to change the classpath you have in your build.gradle file

Comment: in the picture you added, you've used "compile", but that is not in use any longer. You should use "implementation".

Comment: Finally, I've edited the answer to show how you should add the google maven repository to your (project) build.gradle file

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Now I get `Failed to resolve: com.github.ashqal:ChromeLikeSwipeLayout:0.4`. Lets start the chat

Comment: Check out this issue https://github.com/ashqal/ChromeLikeSwipeLayout/issues/11 you need to add the jitpack repository, see my edit

Comment: I am in the chat page. I am getting errors after the edit

Answer (score 2):

`com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1` is old version already.

You can try version `15.0.0` or as *Levi Albuquerque* said `16.0.0`

However just to remind you that if you implement more than one same kind of library, they should be always in the same version to avoid any syncing error.

**Example**

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0'
```

All are same version `15.0.0`

Comment: firebase libs now have independent versions number https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `google()` maven inside your `allProjects` block in your **project** `build.gradle` like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        ...
    }
}

repositories {
    ...
}

// You need to add the google maven in this block.
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For avoid further errors in grandle beacause of a bug try to use:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
```

And for firebase use what you need from below:

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:15.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:15.0.2'
```

- If you using gogle play-services in your grandle set version to 15.0.0 like below example:

  ```
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.0'
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.0'
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.0'
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.0'
  ```

I hope this will help you =)

Comment: @mahmood i think this will help you with your problem, you can also use compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2' instead of implementation but it will be deprecated in he end of 2018.